# Why does it give me BufferUnderflowException

Tags: java, parsing

> The following is the code:

```
byte[] topo1={2,1,1,6,6};
byte[] topo2={2,1,1,2,2};
byte[] topo3={2,5,5,4,4};
byte[] topo4={2,3,3,5,5};
byte[] topo5={2,4,4,3,3};
byte[][] topology = {topo1,topo2,topo3,topo4,topo5};
    writeToLog(String.format("%s receives INIT from nse", routerName));
writeToLog(" ");
parseCircuitDB(topology[routerId-1]);
```

> This the parseCircuitDB method where it shows the error:

```
 private void parseCircuitDB(byte[] string) throws Exception {
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(string);
buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
//gettign the number of neighbor links
nbrLink = buffer.getInt();
System.out.println(nbrLink);
logMsg = String.format("%d neighbor links exist", nbrLink);
writeToLog(logMsg);
for( int i = 1; i <= nbrLink; i++ ) {
    //link id as integer
    int l = buffer.getInt();
   System.out.println(l); 
    //link cost as integer
    int c = buffer.getInt();
    link_cost a = new link_cost(l, c);
    topo_db[routerId].linkCost.put(l, a);
}   
}
```

> I get the error BufferUnderflowException.
>   I tried checking the loops but i dont see any problem there.

Comment: BufferUnderdlowException gets thrown when a relative get operation reaches the source buffer's limit. What does your stack trace say? Can you share it?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
 at java.nio.Buffer.nextGetIndex(Buffer.java:506)
 at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.getInt(HeapByteBuffer.java:361)
 at router.parseCircuitDB(router.java:218)
 at router.ospf(router.java:140)
 at router.<init>(router.java:70)
 at router.main(router.java:483)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The input parameter `string` *(VERY bad name for a `byte[]`)* is an array of 5 bytes, e.g. `02 01 01 06 06` (hex).

You then wrap it in a [`ByteBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) using [`LITTLE_ENDIAN`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteOrder.html#LITTLE_ENDIAN) byte order.

When you then call [`getInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#getInt%28%29), it will consume 4 bytes. Quoting javadoc:

> Reads the next **four bytes** at this buffer's current position, composing them into an int value according to the current byte order, and then increments the position by four.

That is of course because an `int` is a 32-bit integer, requiring four 8-bit bytes for storage.

So that will read the byte `02 01 01 06`, which in [little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) order means `06010102` (hex), which is `100729090` (decimal). *Your `println(nbrLink)` should have told you this already.*

It then enters the loop and calls `getInt()` again, trying to read another 4 bytes, but there is only 1 left, so it throws `BufferUnderflowException`.